# Why is one of my almost identical algorithms works ~10 times faster then other?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am new in programming, so i don't understand some more deeper things. I have a task, to create amount of passwords, with a given numb and longennes of passwords. My first code:

```
from random import choices, choice


def generate_password(m):
    ch = choices('23456789qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmiLQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    return ''.join(ch)


def main(n, m):
    p = set()
    t = 0
    while t < n:
        s = generate_password(m)
        if s not in p:
            t += 1
            p.add(s)
    return p
```

was working, but too long, so then i tried other ways, randomly improving parts of code. So, why is this code so fast? Is it easier to `shuffle()` several times, then just use `choice()` ?

```
from random import choices, shuffle, choice


def generate_password(m):
    global p
    ch = choices('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    while True:
        tt = ''.join(ch)
        if tt in p:
            shuffle(ch)
            continue
        return tt


p = set()


def main(n, m):
    global p
    t = 0
    while t < n:
        p.add(generate_password(m))
        t += 1
    return p
```

```
from time import time
from random import choices, shuffle, choice


def generate_password(m):
    global p
    ch = choices('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    while True:
        tt = ''.join(ch)
        if tt in p:
            shuffle(ch)
            continue
        return tt


p = set()


def main(n, m):
    global p
    t = 0
    while t < n:
        p.add(generate_password(m))
        t += 1
    return p





t1 = time()
print(*main(4609, 3))
t2 = time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

output: 0.05657219886779785

```
from time import time
from random import choices, choice


def generate_password(m):
    ch = choices('23456789qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmiLQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    return ''.join(ch)


def main(n, m):
    p = set()
    t = 0
    while t < n:
        s = generate_password(m)
        if s not in p:
            t += 1
            p.add(s)
    return p





t1 = time()
print(*main(4609, 3))
t2 = time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

I didn't wait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of one of them being faster.

This function:

```
def generate_password(m):
    ch = choices('23456789qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmiLQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    return ''.join(ch)
```

with `m=3`, can only generate 4608 different passwords. The `choices` call generates an **empty** list, because `k=m-3` is 0. Then you make random choices from 2 24-character strings and 1 8-character string, for a total of 24*24*8=4608 possibilities.

Then you try to loop until you've generated 460**9** different passwords. That will never happen.

---

Meanwhile, with this function:

```
def generate_password(m):
    global p
    ch = choices('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM', k=m - 3)
    ch.append(choice('LQWERTYUPASDFGHJKZXCVBNM'))
    ch.append(choice('qwertyupasdfghjkzxcvbnmi'))
    ch.append(choice('23456789'))
    while True:
        tt = ''.join(ch)
        if tt in p:
            shuffle(ch)
            continue
        return tt
```

before the loop, `ch` can again be one of 4608 possibilities. But then if you find the password has already been generated, you shuffle `ch`. This means that the uppercase letter is no longer restricted to be in the first position, and the digit is no longer restricted to be in the end.

This function can generate many more than 4608 possible passwords, so a loop that tries to generate 4609 different passwords with this function can actually end. However, if all 6 permutations of a password have already been generated, this function will keep shuffling `ch` indefinitely.

Comment: The `shuffle` version can generate... 27648 passwords?

Comment: If you wanted to generate good passwords that had at least one capital, at least one lowercase, and at least one digit, then one should have the original form and then shuffle once, and THEN check if it's in the set. That would generate the best passwords.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you generate a random password with `m-2` uppercase letters, one lowercase letter and a digit between 2 and 9, after which it gets added to the set if it is not a duplicate. When you start accumulating passwords, the chances of a duplicate increase, so multiple passwords have to be generated before you get a unique one, which is the slowdown you mention.

Now compare that to the second case, where if the password is a duplicare, you shuffle the characters until it is no longer a duplicate. Now the order of `m-2` capitals, one lowercase and a digit no longer applies, so many more permutations of a password are possible, greatly decreasing the chance of a clash and likely *always* finding it is a unique password.

So the short answer is: **the latter code snippet generates many more unique passwords than the former, decreasing the chance of a duplicate and greatly increasing the execution speed.**